# テンプレートクラスのメンバーの定義の方法

Tags: c++, templates

はじめまして、C++メタプログラミングを最近学び始めたものです。
テンプレートクラスのメンバーの定義の方法（または、フォーマット）についての質問です。
より具体的には、以下のコードの *** (1) *** の部分、template<>、が必要かまたはあれば意味が変わるのかということについてです。template<>があってもなくてもコンパイラからエラーが出ないので混乱してしまいました。とても基本的な質問かもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。

```
template<typename T_Self>
class FrameClass {
public:
    bool frameFunc(const T_Self& org, const T_Self& cmp) const override;
};

class TestClass {
public:
    using Self = TestClass;
private:
    bool testfunc(const Self& cmp) const;
    int a = 1;
};

template<>
class FrameClass<TestClass> {
public:
    using Type = TestClass;
    bool frameFunc(const Type& org, const Type& cmp) const override;
};

template<>  // *** (1) ***
bool FrameClass<TestClass>::frameFunc(const Type& org, const Type& cmp) const {
    bool diff_flg=false;
    if ( ( diff_flg = org.testfunc(cmp) ) ) {
        return diff_flg;
    }
    return diff_flg;
}
```

Comment: このコードは明らかにコンパイルエラーになるはずですが動作確認しましたか？

Comment: 参考:[本の虫:明示的特殊化のややこしさ](http://cpplover.blogspot.jp/2012/09/blog-post_10.html)

Comment: mitei さん、そしてpandamanさん、お返事大変遅れまして申し訳ありません。そして、教えていただきありがとうございました。すでに明示的に特殊化されたものに対しては [template<>]を入れてはいけないのですね。追伸：コンパイル確認（エラー無し確認）だけして動作確認はしていません。次からします。

Comment: エラー無しですか。このコードは数カ所明らかにエラーになる部分があるので、おそらくこのコードを含むファイルがコンパイル対象に含まれていないのだと思います。(1) の部分もおそらくコンパイルエラーになるでしょう。

Comment: mitei さん、追加のコメントありがとうございます。
自分は１年ほど前のeclipse(4.4)+cdt*8.4.0)+gcc4.8.2をc言語用に使っていたのですが、最近になってc++言語の練習用にそれらを使い始めました。もしかするとまだ使い方がよくわかっていないために、上のコードがコンパイル対象から外れるなどの誤作動をさせていたかもしれません。いづれにせよ、ありがとうございました。